# TransactionalPoller is SpringIntegration

Tags: spring-integration

I have QueueChannel with the message-store attribute. Its configuration

```
<int:channel id="channel1">
     <int:queue message-store="msgStore"></int:queue
</int:channel>

<int-jdbc:message-store id="msgStore" data-source="jdbcSQLiteDataSource"/>
```

Then I send messages from this channel to another application using http protocol.
My configuration:

```
 <int-http:outbound-gateway 
    url="someUrl" http-method="PUT"
    request-channel="channel1">

      <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
         <int:retry-advice max-attempts="3">
             <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="2.0" maximum="8000"/>
         </int:retry-advice>
      </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>

 </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

If the receiving application doesn't get my message (e.g. I get the timeout exception from the receiving host)
I want to return this message back out in the channel(channel1).

I use a transactional poller, but it doesn't work. Messages is removed from the channel.

```
<int:poller  default="true"  fixed-rate="100"    receive-timeout="100">
   <int:transactional   transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</int:poller>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jdbcSQLiteDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

**LOG**

```
    DEBUG o.s.i.channel.QueueChannel: preSend on channel 'channel1', message: GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={timestamp=1481896454785, id=90adf115-d76e-3066-de99-ff3b867b66a5}]
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate:    Executing prepared SQL query
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate:    Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(GROUP_KEY) FROM INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]
    DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceUtils: Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
    INFO o.s.j.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource: Established shared JDBC Connection: org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection@1df9e01e


    DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: Acquired Connection [org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection@1df9e01e] for JDBC transaction

    DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceUtils: Changing isolation level of JDBC Connection [org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection@1df9e01e] to 8
    DEBUG o.s.i.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore: Removing messages from group with group key=c5404fa9-4717-38a5-8871-b8761a8414d5
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing SQL batch update [DELETE from   INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY=? and MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?] with a batch size of 100
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL statement [DELETE from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY=? and MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?]
    DEBUG o.s.j.support.JdbcUtils: JDBC driver supports batch updates
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Sending SQL batch update #1 with 1 items


    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing SQL batch update [DELETE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?] with a batch size of 100
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL statement [**DELETE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?]**
    DEBUG o.s.j.support.JdbcUtils: JDBC driver supports batch updates
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Sending SQL batch update #1 with 1 items
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL update
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE INT_MESSAGE_GROUP set UPDATED_DATE=? where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]
    DEBUG o.s.i.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore: Updating MessageGroup: c5404fa9-4717-38a5-8871-b8761a8414d5
    DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: SQL update affected 1 rows
    DEBUG o.s.i.channel.QueueChannel: postReceive on channel 'channel1', message: GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={id=90adf115-d76e-3066-de99-ff3b867b66a5, timestamp=1481896454898, JdbcMessageStore.CREATED_DATE=1481896454898, JdbcMessageStore.SAVED=true}]
    DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer: Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={id=90adf115-d76e-3066-de99-ff3b867b66a5, timestamp=1481896454898, JdbcMessageStore.CREATED_DATE=1481896454898, JdbcMessageStore.SAVED=true}]
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler: o.s.i.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={id=90adf115-d76e-3066-de99-ff3b867b66a5, timestamp=1481896454898, JdbcMessageStore.CREATED_DATE=1481896454898, JdbcMessageStore.SAVED=true}]
    DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate: Retry: count=0
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: outboundHeaderNames=[Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept-Ranges, Authorization, Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Length, Content-Type, Cookie, Date, Expect, From, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Max-Forwards, Pragma, Proxy-Authorization, Range, Referer, TE, Upgrade, User-Agent, Via, Warning]
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[id] WILL NOT be mapped
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[timestamp] WILL NOT be mapped
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[jdbcmessagestore.created_date] WILL NOT be mapped
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[jdbcmessagestore.saved] WILL NOT be mapped

    DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: **Created PUT request for** "http://localhost:8081/test/...

    DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: Writing [1] as "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@1f56e60b]
    DEBUG org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy: Sleeping for 1000
    DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate: Checking for rethrow: count=1
    DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate: Retry: count=1
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: outboundHeaderNames=[Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept-Ranges, Authorization, Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Length, Content-Type, Cookie, Date, Expect, From, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Max-Forwards, Pragma, Proxy-Authorization, Range, Referer, TE, Upgrade, User-Agent, Via, Warning]
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[id] WILL NOT be mapped
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[timestamp] WILL NOT be mapped
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[jdbcmessagestore.created_date] WILL NOT be mapped
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[jdbcmessagestore.saved] WILL NOT be mapped


    DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: **Created PUT request** for "http://localhost:8081/test/...


    DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: Writing [1] as "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@1f56e60b]
    DEBUG org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy: Sleeping for 2000
    DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate: Checking for rethrow: count=2
    DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate: Retry: count=2
    DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: outboundHeaderNames=[Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept-Ranges, Authorization, Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Length, Content-Type, Cookie, Date, Expect, From, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Max-Forwards, Pragma, Proxy-Authorization, Range, Referer, TE, Upgrade, User-Agent, Via, Warning]
   DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[id] WILL NOT be mapped
   DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[timestamp] WILL NOT be mapped
   DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[jdbcmessagestore.created_date] WILL NOT be mapped
   DEBUG o.s.i.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper: headerName=[jdbcmessagestore.saved] WILL NOT be mapped


   DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: **Created PUT request** for "http://localhost:8081/test/...


   DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: Writing [1] as "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@1f56e60b]
   DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate: Checking for rethrow: count=3
   DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate: Retry failed last attempt: count=3
   DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: Initiating transaction rollback
   DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection@1df9e01e]
   DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: Releasing JDBC Connection [org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection@1df9e01e] after transaction
   DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceUtils: Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
   DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel'
   DEBUG o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel: preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:8081/test/...]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8081/test/...": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, headers={timestamp=1481896460962, id=8bff6f2e-ef3a-52bd-5d41-f8785b45a880}]
   DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler: _o.s.i.errorLogger.handler received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:8081/test/...]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8081/test/...": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, headers={timestamp=1481896460962, id=8bff6f2e-ef3a-52bd-5d41-f8785b45a880}]
  ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:8081/test/...]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8081/test/...": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect       
... 

  DEBUG o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel: postSend (sent=true) on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:8081/test/...]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8081/test/...": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, headers={timestamp=1481896460962, id=8bff6f2e-ef3a-52bd-5d41-f8785b45a880}]
  DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: Creating new transaction with name [o.s.i.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE


  DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: Acquired Connection [org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection@1df9e01e] for JDBC transaction
  DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceUtils: Changing isolation level of JDBC Connection [org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection@1df9e01e] to 8
  DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL query
  DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(MESSAGE_ID) from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]
  DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL query
  DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(MESSAGE_ID) from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]
  DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL query
  DEBUG o.s.j.core.JdbcTemplate: Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT INT_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID, INT_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_BYTES from INT_MESSAGE where INT_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID = (SELECT min(m.MESSAGE_ID) from INT_MESSAGE m join INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE on m.MESSAGE_ID = INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID where CREATED_DATE = (SELECT min(CREATED_DATE) from INT_MESSAGE, INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where INT_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID = INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID and INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE.GROUP_KEY = ? and INT_MESSAGE.REGION = ?) and INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE.GROUP_KEY = ? and m.REGION = ?)]
  DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer: Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
  DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: Initiating transaction commit
```

What am I doing is wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs, like I suggested in the answer to your other question?

Comment: @GaryRussell. Yes, I have. I see that SQL delete runs before the http request. Please, see my edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's your database; I am not familiar with SQLLite I just tested it with H2 and everything works as expected...

```
<int:channel id="channel1">
    <int:queue message-store="msgStore" />
</int:channel>

<int-jdbc:message-store id="msgStore"
    data-source="dataSource" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="channel1" expression="1/0">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice>
            <int:fixed-back-off interval="1000" />
        </int:retry-advice>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>

<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="100" receive-timeout="100">
    <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</int:poller>

<jdbc:initialize-database>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:org/springframework/integration/jdbc/schema-h2.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>


@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("context.xml")
public class So41184992Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So41184992Application.class, args);
        context.getBean("channel1", MessageChannel.class).send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Result:

```
10:22:42.680 [task-scheduler-1] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: 1/0; nested exception is java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
...
10:22:44.690 [task-scheduler-1] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: 1/0; nested exception is java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
```

With the exceptions occurring every 2 seconds (3 attempts with 1 second delay).

**EDIT**

By the way, it's generally better to use a `JdbcChannelMessageStore` to back channels rather than a generic message store - it's optimized for channels (as opposed to message groups for aggregation etc).

```
<bean id="msgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.H2ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:org/springframework/integration/jdbc/store/channel/schema-h2.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

You would need to provide a custom query-provider for a non-standard database, though.

Comment: You may not understand me. See, I set the attribute max-attempts=3. I want to  return this message back out in the channel after 3 failed attempts. Is it possible?

Comment: That's exactly what my test case does - the default `maxAttempts` is 3.

Comment: Gary, you're right. Your example works as expected. My problem was that I used org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource. Thank